# How to search lines contain string in file.txt

Tags: java, file, filereader

i have problem when i want to search string line in file this is my code

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws SQLException
    {
        try{
        //System.out.println( "Hello World!" );
             RepositoryFactory.emf=Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("onezero");
        String Symbol = "EURUSD";
        TradingHistory tradingHistorys = RepositoryFactory.getTradingHistoryRepo().findPriceEmpty(Symbol);
        String symbols = tradingHistorys.getSymbol();
        String created = tradingHistorys.getCreated_at();
        String[] createds = created.split(" ");
        String tanggal = createds[0];
        String times = createds[1];
        String timeSearch = tanggal.concat("T").concat(times);
        String pathfile = "/home/ec2-user/saveFile/";
        String filesearch = pathfile.concat(tanggal).concat("-").concat(symbols).concat(".txt");
        SearchFile(timeSearch,filesearch);

        System.out.print(symbols+"|"+created+"|"+filesearch+timeSearch);
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.print(e);
    }
    }
```

and here my method for search String in file

```
private static void SearchFile(String timeSearch, String filesearch) {
        String line = null;
        ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();
         try {
                FileReader fReader = new FileReader(filesearch);
                BufferedReader fileBuff = new BufferedReader(fReader);
                while ((line = fileBuff.readLine()) != null) {
                    fileContents.add(line);
                }
                fileBuff.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
         System.out.println(fileContents.contains(timeSearch));
    }
```

and when i use

```
Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(filesearch));
          int lineID = 0;
          java.util.List lineNumbers = new ArrayList();
          Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile(timeSearch);
          Matcher matcher = null;
          while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                lineID++;
                matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if(matcher.find()){
                    lineNumbers.add(lineID);

                }


            }
            System.out.println(lineNumbers);
        }
```

i got [183394, 183395, 183396, 183397, 183398, 183399, 183400, 183401, 183402, 183403, 183404, 183405, 183406]

when i run my code i got error there is false.
but when i search manual there the value is

name of file is  2020-05-05-EURUSD.txt 
    EUR/USD|1.09031|2020-05-05T04:30:17.008
    EUR/USD|1.0903|2020-05-05T04:30:17.046
    EUR/USD|1.09029|2020-05-05T04:30:17.211
    EUR/USD|1.0903|2020-05-05T04:30:17.340
    EUR/USD|1.09027|2020-05-05T04:30:17.348
    EUR/USD|1.0903|2020-05-05T04:30:17.509
    EUR/USD|1.09027|2020-05-05T04:30:17.518
    EUR/USD|1.0903|2020-05-05T04:30:17.547
    EUR/USD|1.09027|2020-05-05T04:30:17.558
    EUR/USD|1.0903|2020-05-05T04:30:17.712
    EUR/USD|1.09027|2020-05-05T04:30:17.718
    EUR/USD|1.0903|2020-05-05T04:30:17.841
    EUR/USD|1.09027|2020-05-05T04:30:17.848

how to fix search string in the file.txt ?

and this is the log what i got

```
false
EURUSD|2020-05-05 04:30:17|2020-05-05 04:30:17/home/ec2-user/saveFile/2020-05-05-EURUSD.txt2020-05-05T04:30:17
```

Comment: You are not searching whether your individual lines _contain_ the string you specified, you are searching for an exact match in your list of lines. Try modifying `fileContents.contains(timeSearch)` into a stream/loop that checks every element if it contains your search string.

Comment: @wjans any example for stream or looping use ?

Comment: Have a look at [java.util.Stream.anyMatch(Predicate)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)).  The internet is full of examples regarding this use case.

Comment: hi @wjans i have got line contains thats string [183394, 183395, 183396, 183397, 183398, 183399, 183400, 183401, 183402, 183403, 183404, 183405, 183406]
but my question is how to get the string from that line ?

Comment: it done right now after i add String lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filesearch)).get(lineID);
     System.out.println(lines);

Answer (score 0):

fileContents.contains(timeSearch)
checks if any element of fileContents (each line of your file) are equal to timeSearch

you should use `String contains()` method for each element of fileContents (each line of your file)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String filePath2 = Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString();
    String path = filePath2.concat("\\files\\2020-05-05-EURUSD.txt");
    searchFile("2020-05-05T04:30:17", path);
}

private static void searchFile(String timeSearch, String filesearch) {
    String line = null;
    ArrayList<String> fileContents = new ArrayList<String>();
     try {
            FileReader fReader = new FileReader(filesearch);
            BufferedReader fileBuff = new BufferedReader(fReader);
            while ((line = fileBuff.readLine()) != null) {
                fileContents.add(line);
            }
            fileBuff.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
     System.out.println(fileContents.contains(timeSearch));

     boolean result =false;
     for (String elementOfArrayList : fileContents) {
        if(elementOfArrayList.contains(timeSearch)) {
            result=true;
            break;
        }
    }
     System.out.println(result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static  void SearchFile(String timeSearch, String filesearch) throws IOException {
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(new File(filesearch));
          int lineID = 0;
          java.util.List lineNumbers = new ArrayList();
          ArrayList<Double> list = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
          Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile(timeSearch);
          Matcher matcher = null;
          while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
                lineID++;
                matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
                if(matcher.find()){
                    lineNumbers.add(lineID);
                    String lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filesearch)).get(lineID);
                    String[] LineGetPrice = lines.split("\\|", 2);
                    String price = LineGetPrice[1];
                    String[] pricestringArray = price.split("\\|", 2);
                    String prices=pricestringArray[0];
                    Double priced = Double.parseDouble(prices);
                    list.add(priced);
                    //Double MinPrice = getMinValue(list);
                    System.out.println(lines+prices);
                    //System.out.println(list);
                }


            }
            System.out.println(lineNumbers);
            System.out.println(list);
            Double MinPrice = getMinValue(list);
            System.out.println(list+"|"+MinPrice);

        }
```

i have update and use this code i can get price and all line for match the data

thanks for all who help me here